# Object Reference Not Set to Instance of an Object

Tags: c#

Is my machine playing me today?

When I run the `TestConnectionString()` method of this object I get the error at the connection string setting.

```
public class CustomerDAL
{
   string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].Name;

    public CustomerDAL()
    {

    }

    public string TestConnection()
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn =  new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();

        if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            return "Open";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Close";
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `ConnectionStrings["myConnection"]` returns null, then dereferencing it to get the `Name` property will fail in the constructor. Is that definitely not where the bug is?

Why not put a breakpoint on that line and take a look in `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` to check what it *thinks* it's got - and check *very* carefully for typos.

After that, put a breakpoint on the first line of the method, and check what the value of `connectionString` is. Passing in `null` to the `SqlConnection` constructor doesn't actually throw an exception, but you'd get an `InvalidOperationException` when you try to open it.

Comment: Jon ~ I should've known better. I've got my StackOverFlowed. It was under "appSettings" section.

Answer (score 1):

I have three suggestions

1. you need to add  a .dll reference for configuration manager
2. recheck if your connection string is right
3. check if you have more than one configuration file ex. web.config and app.config; so the ConfigurationManager is referencing the wrong file in the solution.