# The type initializer for object threw an exception

Tags: vb.net, class, initialization

I am getting a run-time error "The type initializer for 'SensionVB.CommonCall' threw an exception." when trying instantiate the object call:

```
Dim general As New SensionVB.CommonCall
```

When stepping through the code once it hits the above line in code and fails, it does .

The suggestions from Microsoft are to check for null, or add new neither is true in this case

SensionVB = Project
CommonCall = Public Class with various functions

```
Public Class CommonCall
Protected WithEvents litOne As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal
Public Shared sConnection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SerialStamperConnectionString").ConnectionString
Public Shared oConnection As New MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(sConnection)
Public Shared sMaxSerialNumber As String = "S000001"
Public Shared bLoggedin As Boolean = False
Public Shared iPageWidth As Integer = 1024

Public Shared isValidPassword As Boolean = False
Public Shared strCompanyID As String = ""
Public Shared strSecurityID As String = ""

Dim Response As New HttpResponse(HttpWriter.Null)
Const TimeOutInMinutes As Integer = 60
Const SiteTitle As String = "SensiOn"
Public Const PageWidth As Integer = 1250
Public SSOenabled As Boolean
Const SuperUserEmails As String = "super@domain.com"
Public Sub Initialize()
    oConnection.Open()
End Sub
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Please show the code for the static constructor (`Shared Sub New`) of class CommonCall

Comment: By looking at this I'm guessing that this is the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699409/object-reference-not-set-to-instance-of-an-object

Comment: If this is throwing an exception on instantiating an instance of the class, we need to see the instance constructor. Please provide the code for `Public Sub New()` above. (This is not the same as the suggestion from jeroenh. A static constructor would not throw an exception during the creation of an instance of a class.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see three lines that may possibly be the culprit:

---

```
Public Shared sConnection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SerialStamperConnectionString").ConnectionString
```

There are several potential issues here. One, your connection string name ("SerialStamperConnectionString") is incorrect. If this name does not match a key in the web.config, then it will return `Nothing`, causing a NullReferenceException when you attempt to get the value of the `ConnectionString` property.

---

```
Public Shared oConnection As New MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(sConnection)
```

It's possible that your connection string above is not configured properly in the web.config, thus returning `Nothing` as the ConnectionString. If sConnection has been set to `Nothing`, it's possible that a NullReferenceException could be thrown my the MysqlConnection constructor.

---

```
Dim Response As New HttpResponse(HttpWriter.Null)
```

If `HttpWriter.Null` is `Nothing` then this could also be the source of your problem (for the same reason noted above).

---

If none of these suggestions seem to be causing the problem, then I would suggest posting more information about your issue (including the stack trace). Offering a million reputation points will not give us any additional information about your code.

---

**ADDENDUM**
According to the VB documentation on Shared constructors (and, by extension, members):

> Exactly when shared constructors are run is mostly implementation dependent, though several guarantees are provided if a shared constructor is explicitly defined:
>
> - Shared constructors are run before any instance of a class type is created.
> - Shared constructors are run before any instance members of a structure type are accessed, or before any constructor of a structure type is explicitly called. Calling the implicit parameterless constructor created for structures will not cause the shared constructor to run.
> - Shared constructors are run before any of the type's shared members are referenced.
> - Shared constructors are run before any types that derive from the type are loaded.
> - A shared constructor will not be run more than once during a single execution of a program.
>
> [9.3.2 Shared Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711965%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

You may find it useful to create a Shared constructor in which to initialize your shared fields:

```
Public Shared sConnection As String
Public Shared oConnection As MySqlClient.MySqlConnection

Shared Sub New()
    Dim l_connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SerialStamperConnectionString")
    If l_connectionString IsNot Nothing Then
        sConnection = l_connectionString.ConnectionString
        oConnection = New MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(sConnection)
    Else
        ' What to do here?
    End If
End Sub
```

This will not solve your problem, most likely, but it may make it easier to find and to handle (null string, etc.)

Comment: Not sure this is it as it fails at instantiation of the call. When I have stepped through it in the past as soon as the code sees the call it throws the error it never steps into the class itself.

Comment: Shared values are evaluated once before the first instantiation. The error would occur before the debugger reaches the constructor.

Comment: @Sean - Please see the updated answer. I've added some info about shared constructors which may be useful/helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This line will probably make it fail:

```
Dim Response As New HttpResponse(HttpWriter.Null)
```

as it is initialized at the same time. Try setting this to:

```
Dim Response As HttpResponse = Nothing
```

and initialize it in the code for initializing instead.There you can also check if you get a null object.

you are also doing some initializations assuming you get correct results in your shared variables:

```
Public Shared oConnection As New MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(sConnection)
```

These will not affect initialization as they are shared, but it is bad practice IMO.

Instead of `Initialize()`, why not use `New()`:

```
Public Sub New()
    'TODO move init. of Response to here.
    'TODO move init. of oConnection to here.
    oConnection.Open() 'TODO error check
End Sub
```

Comment: Trust me that is just the tip of the iceberg as far as bad practice goes. In total this is a website that works in IIS but does not compile in Visual Studio. My job ids to clean it up. stage one is to compile it, stage 2 refactor like a mad man. stage 3..., stage 4 profit